# Como preencher setText do TextView a partir de um ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

Eu recebo um *array* com itens de interesses e devo setá-los no `setText` de um determinado `TextView`.

Quero que apareçam todos os itens deste array, na tela, na horizontal. Em meu xml de layout, somente coloquei 1 textView para receber todos os itens que vierem neste array.

Minha dúvida, tenho que montar um ListView, na horizontal, para receber este array e apresentá-lo na tela? Ou, posso simplesmente pegar os itens e colocá-los na propriedade setText deste TextView?

Segue o código:

```
@BindView(R.id.txtInterests)
TextView txt_interests;

CommunityPresenter presenter;
UserCommunity selectedUser;
List<String> interest = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Fade());
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ride_request);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    presenter = new CommunityPresenter(this);

    first.setText(presenter.getDay(0));
    second.setText(presenter.getDay(1));
    third.setText(presenter.getDay(2));

    user = new SessionManager();

    selectedUser = CommunityService.i(getContext()).selectedUser;
    reloadView();

    send_offer_request.setOnClickListener(presenter.sendRequestOnClickListener(0));
    send_ask_request.setOnClickListener(presenter.sendRequestOnClickListener(1));

    populateInterests();


}

private void populateInterests() {
    RequestManager.UsersInterests(selectedUser.id, new FutureCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

            //array com os interesses
            interest = new Gson().fromJson(new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject().get("data").toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType());

            txt_interests.setText(); //preencher o TextView com os interesses

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Olá Henrique, fica mais fácil te dar uma resposta concreta se você editar sua pergunta e explicar o que exatamente quer apareça em `txt_interests`. Se pode ser qualquer coisa (em qualquer formato) a resposta pode ser simplesmente `txt_interests.setText(interest.toString());` (que vai exibir algo como `[Interesse1, Interesse2, Interesse3]`).

Comment: Editei, mas é basicamente o que estava na pergunta mesmo. Gostaria de saber como pode ser feito para que seja apresentado como textos na tela, ao receber este array com os itens.

Comment: Oi Henrique, veja se a sugestão no comentário acima resolve (acho que foi isso que o Victor quis dizer na resposta dele também). É claro que visualmente uma *List View* com um item para cada interesse é bem diferente de uma *Text View*  com todos os interesses concatenados em uma única String, mas o que é melhor depende da aplicação. Ou sua dúvida é outra?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly seria uma parte a questão da lógica, resolvida pelo "toString" e qual seria melhor. Mas consegui entender aqui. Pode colocar como resposta que marco. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Oi @Henrique, sem problemas. Acho que as respostas atuais já estão tratando do que eu iria escrever, então fique a vontade para aceitar a que melhor se encaixar ao seu problema (assumindo que ele esteja resolvido)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com seu questionamento, vou tentar responder de forma simples baseando nos dados e código que você disponibilizou.

Pelo que percebemos, você declarou uma variável do tipo `List<String>` cujo nome é `interest`, que ocasionalmente seriam os interesses que você quer atribuir ao seu `TextView`.

Para que você capture cada item, é necessário você percorrer toda sua lista. Existem diversas maneiras de você percorrer e capturar elementos de uma lista e uma delas é usar um `foreach`. Abaixo segue um exemplo bem básico:

```
String interests = "";
for(String str: interest){
    interests+="\n"+str;
}
txt_interests.setText(interests);
```

Como de preferência sua, querendo que apareça os itens na horizontal, eu inserir um `\n` para fazer uma quebra de linha no qual o próximo "interesse" aparecerá uma abaixo do outro.

#### Atualização

Como nosso amigo ressaltou nos comentário, existe [uma discussão antiga](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076072/build-ci-sdlc/stringbuffer-versus-string.html) que frequentemente aparece no Java que é o uso errado da concatenação de Strings, que pode acarretar numa perda de performance e [*trashing* de memória](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

O uso do operador `+` parece inocente, mas o código gerado produz algumas surpresas. Usando um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para concatenação pode na verdade produzir um código que é significativamente mais rápido do que usando um `String`. Segue abaixo:

```
StringBuilder interests = new StringBuilder();
for(String str: interest){
    interests.append("\n").append(str);
}
txt_interests.setText(interests);
```

Para saber mais detalhes, você pode ler [este artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/diferencas-entre-string-stringbuilder-e-stringbuffer-em-java/29865) que fala sobre as diferenças entre `String`, `StringBuilder` e `StringBuffer` em Java.

Comment: Oi seamusd, boa resposta. O único detalhe de implementação seria a concatenação dentro de um laço. Enquanto o compilador [tenta otimizar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) esse tipo de coisa, vale a pena ser explícito e usar um `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer adicionar tudo em um `TextView` só, é só concatenar as informações da sua lista e adicionar no `setText`.

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta. Eu quero colocar no setText do textView. Eu teria que criar uma lista, personalizada?