# Criar TextView's dinamicamente

Tags: java, android, layout

Tenho um `TextView` e gostaria que, em vez do preenchimento com um `Arraylist`, com todos os itens em seu `setText`, que ele fosse criado várias vezes na tela, com os respectivos itens deste array, em cada `setText` de cada `TextView`.

Segue o código:

```
public class RideRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CommunityRequestView {

    private SessionManager user;
    private String departure;
    private String arrival;



    @BindView(R.id.request_email)
    TextView email;


    @BindView(R.id.request_name)
    TextView name;


    @BindView(R.id.request_photo)
    ImageView photo;


    @BindView(R.id.textView_first)
    TextView first;

    @BindView(R.id.textView_second)
    TextView second;

    @BindView(R.id.textView_third)
    TextView third;

    @BindView(R.id.button0)
    CheckBox button0;

    @BindView(R.id.button1)
    CheckBox button1;

    @BindView(R.id.button2)
    CheckBox button2;

    @BindView(R.id.button3)
    CheckBox button3;

    @BindView(R.id.button4)
    CheckBox button4;

    @BindView(R.id.button5)
    CheckBox button5;

    @BindView(R.id.send_offer_request)
    Button send_offer_request;

    @BindView(R.id.send_ask_request)
    Button send_ask_request;

    @BindView(R.id.txtInterests)
    TextView mListView;

    @BindView(R.id.img_favorite)
    ImageView imgFavorite;

    CommunityPresenter presenter;
    UserCommunity selectedUser;
    UsersMySQLiteHelper serviceDB;
    private List<UserCommunity> userInterest = new ArrayList<UserCommunity>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Fade());
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ride_request);
        serviceDB = new UsersMySQLiteHelper(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext());

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        presenter = new CommunityPresenter(this);


        first.setText(presenter.getDay(0));
        second.setText(presenter.getDay(1));
        third.setText(presenter.getDay(2));

        user = new SessionManager();

        selectedUser = CommunityService.i(getContext()).selectedUser;
        reloadView();

        send_offer_request.setOnClickListener(presenter.sendRequestOnClickListener(0));
        send_ask_request.setOnClickListener(presenter.sendRequestOnClickListener(1));
        imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedUser.favorite == 0) {
                    selectedUser.favorite = 1;
                    imgFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_on_48px);
                }else{
                    selectedUser.favorite = 0;
                    imgFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_off_48px);
                }
                selectedUser.save(serviceDB, user.getLoggedUser().getCompany());
            }
        });

        populateInterests();
        getPoints();

        imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_favorite);
        if (selectedUser.favorite == 0){
            imgFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_off_48px);
        }else{
            imgFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_on_48px);
        }




    }

    private void getPoints() {
    }

    private void populateInterests() {
        RequestManager.UsersInterests(selectedUser.id, new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                if(e== null || result != null) {
                    UserCommunity user = new Gson().fromJson(new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject().get("data").toString(),
                            UserCommunity.class);

                    selectedUser.interests = user.interests;
                    String name = "";
                    TextView txt_Interests = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInterests);
                    for (UserCommunity.Interest interest: selectedUser.interests
                         ) {
                           name += interest.name + " ";
                           txt_Interests.setText(name);
                    }
                    String point = "";
                    TextView points = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Points);
                    selectedUser.points = user.points;
                    point = selectedUser.points + "\npontos";
                    points.setText(point);

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/request_photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar5"
        android:transitionName="infoboxImage" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/request_photo"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_off_48px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/request_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_favorite"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Abraao Barros Lacerda"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display1"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:transitionName="infoboxName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/request_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/request_name"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="abraaobarros3@gmail.com" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_points"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/request_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Points"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img_points"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_points"
            android:text="50.000 pontos" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_interests"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_Points"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtInterests"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="INTERESTS"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/txt_border_circle"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear_interests">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_first"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.03"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Segunda-feira"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button0"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.03"
                        android:text="Ida - 7:00" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.03"
                        android:text="Volta -18:00" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/card_1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_second"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Quarta-Feira"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Ida - 7:00" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Volta -18:00" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/card_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_third"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Quinta-Feira"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Ida - 7:00" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Volta -18:00" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_offer_request"
                style="@style/ByndButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/card_3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Oferecer carona" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_ask_request"
                style="@style/ByndButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/card_3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Pedir carona" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Melhoria para esta questão, que eu mesmo coloquei: [Como preencher setText do TextView a partir de um ArrayList?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171487/como-preencher-settext-do-textview-a-partir-de-um-arraylist)

Comment: Não entendir... tem como explicar melhor o que está querendo dizer com: "...em vez do preenchimento com um arraylist..."

Comment: @seamusd como na questão anterior, eu pegava todos os itens do array e colocava em um setText de um textView na tela. Eu gostaria é que cada item do array, estivesse, separadamente em cada setText de cada textView criado, dinamicamente na tela. Para que fiquem separados, no layout e não separados por espaços como está hoje. Fui mais claro?

Comment: A resposta do nosso amigo abaixo resolve seu problema. Tente implementar da maneira que ele mostrou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo:

**XML:**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mContent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**JAVA:**

```
/**
 * Layout que irá receber os TextView
 */
LinearLayout mContent = LinearLayout.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.mContent));
/**
 * Lista de TextView que serão criados dinamicamente
 */
List<TextView> textos = new ArrayList<>();

// Ponteiroi 
int idPt = 1;
 for (UserCommunity.Interest interest: selectedUser.interest) {
    // Vamos criar a a instancia do TExtView
    final TextView txtItem = new TextView(this);  
    // Informamos um id 
    txtItem.setId( idPt );   
    idPt++;
    txtItem.setText(interest.name);
    // Vamos adicionar um Layout ao TextView 
    toggleButton.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // Adicionamos no Linear Layout
    mContent.addView(toggleButton);
    // Adicionamos em uma lista para guarda a referencia, 
    // Caso precise manipular novamente os objetos
    textos.add(toggleButton);


}
```

Comment: Luiz Não deu certo, a variável idPt fica como incorreta no código, sublinhada de vermelho, como erro. E não consigo achar com o this, o list textos.

Comment: Você deve utilizar o **this** apenas se  ela form uma variável global (da classe). Qual erro ocorre com a variável **idPt**???

Comment: funcionou aqui, quase igual a sua resposta

Comment: É um exemplo, aí você adapta a sua necessidade

Comment: Sim, valeu demais!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar desta forma definindo um `LinearLayout` dentro do `.xml`:

#### JAVA

```
LinearLayout llayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

for (int i = 0; i<selectedUser.interests.size(); i++) {
    final TextView txtItem = new TextView(this);
    txtItem.setId(i);
    point = user.points.get(i).toString() + "\npontos";
    txtItem.setText(""+point);
    llayout.addView(txtItem);
}
```

#### XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @HenriqueMendes conseguiu resolver seu problema ou precisa de mais alguma coisa?

Comment: consegui, muito obrigado! Coloquei a resposta como queria

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente como resolvi, de acordo com as respostas no post:

```
private void populateInterests() {
    RequestManager.UsersInterests(selectedUser.id, new FutureCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
            if (e == null || result != null) {
                UserCommunity user = new Gson().fromJson(new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject().get("data").toString(),
                        UserCommunity.class);
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_interests);
                selectedUser.interests = user.interests;
                String name = "";
                // TextView txt_Interests = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInterests);
                for (UserCommunity.Interest interest : selectedUser.interests) {
                    final TextView txt_Interests = new TextView(AppController.getAppContext());
                    txt_Interests.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.txt_border_circle);
                    txt_Interests.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    name = interest.name;
                    txt_Interests.setText(name);
                    layout.addView(txt_Interests);

                }
                String point = "";
                TextView points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Points);
                selectedUser.points = user.points;
                point = selectedUser.points + "\npontos";
                points.setText(point);

            }
        }
    });

}
```